# Anyone remember an anime about a girl whom her sister killed and became a plant monster to protect her sister?

Tags: story-identification, anime

It aired around 2000-2010. It's an anime in which the girl woke up and found herself in a lab where she lost her memory about her sister's death.

Comment: You can increase the chances of someone answering this post by adding more details, and by clarifying the story. It's not completely clear to me what happened in the story. If I have read it correctly, a girl A kills her sister B. B becomes a plant monster. Then A (or is it B?) wakes up in the lab. Or does that happen before she becomes a plant monster...?

Answer (score 4):

I think is the movie *[King of Thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_Thorn)*.

Some epidemic is happening, two sisters [twins if not mistaken] are chosen or only one, and many other people are chosen to hibernate and wake up 100 years later or so.  When they wake up plants and other weird creatures now rule the place..  Something down the end of the movie,  they mentioned how one sister died and how she did something to save the other one, or something like that,  of the whole plant thing.